# Jmeter -- sending files from JMS-publisher sampler to ActiveMQ

Tags: jmeter, jms, activemq-classic, publisher

For my test case, I need to send full messages (with header & properties) to ActiveMQ and have messages in JSON file format using JMS-publisher sampler.

How can I send JSON files (or files in any format) from JMS-publisher sampler to ActiveMQ?

Or how can I send full messages to ActiveMQ from JMS-publisher sampler?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to test ActiveMQ's performance by a test plan from JMeter. I have some messages in .json file format and I can get zipped file of the same messages from ActiveMQBrowser (includes properties, header and payload). It is important to use these messages because consumption of these messages is based on some filter definition in ActiveMQ.

Comment: In short, need to dynamically create messages with JMS headers and properties, something like: JMSType=ABC; myProp="someTExt"; body="thePayload" and with different values for each messages

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody interested:

The message content or files cannot be used for adding JMS headers or properties.
Using a JSR223 PreProcessor and grrovy, I managed to reconstruct every message with new message body, headers and properties.

Thanks to: https://jmetervn.com/2016/12/20/jsr223-with-groovy-variables-part-2/